# ExtensionSettings Schema Validation Error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've created a Chrome extension and I'm trying to use managed settings. My policy from ExtensionSettings shows up in chrome://policy and when I show value, it has the correctly processed compact JSON which I have formatted like:

```
{"myextensionid":{"setting1":"value", "setting2":"value"}}
```

This shows up in the Chrome policies section of the chrome://policy page with a status of `Schema validation error at "(ROOT)": Unknown property: setting1`

When I check the checkbox for `Show policies with no value set` and scroll past all the Chrome policies, I can see a section for with my extension's name and ID. All of the schema values that I supplied in my schema.json file referenced in the manifest are listed (thus my manifest and schema within the extension seem fine) are listed with a status of `Not set.`

Since the documentation on this is awful, does anyone have advice on how to properly set the managed policy values for my extension using group policy? I'm able to configure the policy values using the registry like [Configuring Apps and Extensions by Policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions) covers, but it mentions being able to set those with GPO. I've installed the [Policy Templates](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) for Chrome but there doesn't seem to be any policy that lets me set 3rd party extension policies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with managed storage but the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) shows a totally different syntax.

Comment: The documentation for managed storage that I found is https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionSettings that shows an example:

Comment: Those are preset policies, not Managed Storage, you can't use arbitrary settings there.

Comment: So then where do you set the values for managed storage properties?

Comment: The link you posted shows how to configure the extension which defines the schema for the policies. I've done that and my policies show up in chrome://policy so they seem to be *defined* alright. What I'm looking for is how an administrator can set the values for the policies that I defined.

Comment: Maybe [Configuring Apps and Extensions by Policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions) linked in that article?